# Breaking one grid layout into two pieces

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I want to split a grid layout filled with buttons into two pieces, where the first 5 buttons can go into the north of a `BorderLayout` and the last 5 can go into the south.

```
    myPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 1, 5, 10));
    final JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

Comment: Wonderful! What have you tried? Just put your buttons into panels and add those panels to your `mainPanel`'s `BorderLayout`.

Comment: Create three panels, use two to display buttons and the third to display them. You can use a GridLayout for all three

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of options, using only a single panel, you can change the `GridLayout` properties to allow for 5 columns and 2 rows...

[image: Couple of rows]

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 10));
for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    panel.add(new JButton(Integer.toString(index)));
}
```

Or, you could make use three panels, one acting as the outer container, defining the rows, and the others defining the rows

[image: Couple of more rows]

```
JPanel outer = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));

JPanel topRow = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 5));
for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    topRow.add(new JButton(Integer.toString(index)));
}
JPanel bottomRow = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 5));
for (int index = 5; index < 10; index++) {
    bottomRow.add(new JButton(Integer.toString(index)));
}

outer.add(topRow);
outer.add(bottomRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will help you ;) You need to add the action listeners to your buttons.

```
  final JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

---

```
  JPanel northPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 5));

  JButton b1 = new Button("Button 1");
  northPanel.add(b1);

  (...) (Add the other 4 buttons)

  mainPanel.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

---

```
  JPanel southPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 5));

  JButton b6 = new Button("Button 6");
  southPanel .add(b6);

  (...) (Add the other 4 buttons)

  mainPanel.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
myPanelNorth = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 1, 5, 10));
myPanelSouth = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 1, 5, 10));

BorderLayout b = new BorderLayout()
final JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

mainPanel.add(myPanelNorth , b.NORTH);
mainPanel.add(myPanelSouth , b.SOUTH);
```

then add your buttons to north and the south separately